# How can I make my Upstart service depend on PostgreSQL?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, upstart

I have a service configured as an upstart job. How do I make sure that PostgreSQL is running before my service is started? Ubuntu 14.04 here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the PostgreSQL has not yet been made Upstart aware. That complicates things. You could just check for the existence of a PID file for your version/cluster, but then what do you do if it's not there?

I chose to link the start of my service (pgagent) with the start of a pg cluster. This works for me, but it might not for you. Also pgagent is too forky (forks more than twice) for upstart to track its PID, so I can't use the `respawn` stanza. Your service might be OK.

For an example of using the cluster start up to launch a service via Upstart see my adventures [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225018/postgresql-configuring-as-upstart-job-problem/414337#414337).

Comment: I was expecting a "can't be done", but this is the best kind of such an answer :)